# access public ip from localhost timeout on https

Tags: linux, nginx, https

I'm setting up a server to share files with some friends and familly. Everything works just fine with HTTP, but since I setup HTTPS this morning, I can't reach the server through the public ip/domain name I setup, I'm getting timeout. It works fine outside of my local network, I can reach it from my phone on LTE, and my friends can reach it too.

Here's my nginx config file, I set up a redirection from HTTP to HTTPS

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name DOMAIN;

    location / {
        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /var/www/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name DOMAIN;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/uacme/DOMAIN/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/uacme/private/DOMAIN/key.pem;
    root        /pool/media;
    autoindex   on;
    charset     utf-8;
    
    location / {
        add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /var/www/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }
}
```

From localhost, I can reach the domain through HTTP and get a correct 302, but reaching HTTPS will timeout.

```
$ curl -I http://DOMAIN
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
$ curl -I --resolve 'DOMAIN:443:LOCALIP' https://DOMAIN
HTTP/2 200 
$ curl -I https://DOMAIN
curl: (28) Failed to connect to DOMAIN port 443 after 128882 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I have setup `ufw` on the server, with the correct configuration to allow traffic on the port 80 and 443. Could this be a problem on the router itself? I have tried several tool online that all points to a healthy server, only my local network is affected.

Comment: See what OpenSSL `s_client` tells, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html

Comment: Im getting `483B54CFC27F0000:error:8000006F:system library:BIO_connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:114:calling connect()` with errno 111

Comment: That very much matches what curl printed out. A TCP connection (SSL/TLS) cannot be created with the resolved IP address and port 443. Then what device owns that IP address? A router or something else? That's what you should check first.

Comment: The IP is my public IP, the router forwards the traffic on that port to my server. I'm trying to curl from the same server through the https url. Doing `openssl s_client -connect DOMAIN:443` returns errno 110 this time.